# Async Task to Save data in SQL server in Android

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I am trying to save edit box data in SQL server by using android app. I am trying to use async task  to save data.I already developed web service and host in the IIS which is running fine. So i Need now code in android to save data.

This is my Aysnc Task

```
class SaveScan extends  AsyncTask<String,Void, String>{

    String status = null;

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }
    protected  String doInBackground(String... connUrl){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader reader;

        try{
            final URL url = new URL(connUrl[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json: charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");;

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("scans",Scan1);

            OutputStream out  = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            out.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
            out.close();

            int result = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (result == 200) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while((line =reader.readLine()) != null){
                    status = line;
                }

            }

        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
        return  status;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result != null){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Scan Saved ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Not Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Mine Button Call

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    100);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scan.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: user this link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: https://medium.com/@ajaysaini.official/building-database-with-room-persistence-library-ecf7d0b8f3e9

Comment: where are you starting your asynctask ?

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman not able to save data

Comment: have you tried the same web service in postman?If not please check there first you will came to know the problem

Comment: in Btn click try to call your async task like new SaveScan ().execute();

Answer (score 1):

```
private void onSaveClicked() {
        new SaveScan(url).execute();
 }


     private class SaveScan extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String>{
        String status = null;
        protected  String doInBackground(String... connUrl){

            try {
                // This is getting the url from the string we passed in
                URL url = new URL(connUrl[0]);

                // Create the urlConnection
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");


                // OPTIONAL - Sets an authorization header
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "someAuthString");

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("scans","someString");
                // Send the post body
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
                writer.flush();

                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (statusCode ==  200) {

                    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                    String response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    status=response ;
                    // From here you can convert the string to JSON with whatever JSON parser you like to use

                } else {
                    // Status code is not 200
                    // Do something to handle the error
                    status=null;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("SaveScan", e.getMessage());
            }
            return  status;
        }
        private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result != null){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Scan Saved ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Not Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: private void onSaveClicked() {
        new SaveScan(url).execute();
 }          url is throwing error

Comment: replacing your with your url

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between different storage frameworks such as **Room, SQLite or Preferences** depending on your data. Room and SQLite are relational databases, where SQLite requires developers to create tables and map relationships, Room takes care of those with the help of annotation processing. Preferences are android's storage framework where you can store minimal amount of data for example settings for your app, map app's flow and vital data such as user information. In the end, it all depends on the time you can spend and the data that you are trying to save. I suggest you go through all these frameworks and identify what's best for you.

Comment: Here i am saving using WCF service to save data and i am calling on btnsave